# Introductory C++ program

Tags: c++

I have tried tirelessly to get this right, but nothing seems to work.  A lot of what I do brings me to an error 'Control may reach end of non-void function'.

Basically, we created a program to output gas usage statistics.  What I am stuck on is:
  "Gas will rise in price from the defined initial value to the defined final value over the course of 4 years, then remain fixed at that higher value for the next 4 years."

I feel like there should be a loop or function for this, but every time I make NUM_YEARS an int rather than a const, no matter what the program tells me 'Control may reach end of non-void function.'

Below is the program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MILES_PER_YEAR = 21000;
const double CITY_PERCENT = 45.0;
const double HIGHWAY_PERCENT = 55.0;
const double CITY_MPG = 51.0;
const double HIGHWAY_MPG = 45.0;
const double USABLE_GAS = 9.0;
const double INITIAL_PRICE = 3.359;
const double FINAL_PRICE = 6.00;
const int NUM_YEARS = 8; //This will be the total number of years

double gasPrice(int day);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   cout << "Driving the Toyota Prius" << endl;
   double daily_miles = MILES_PER_YEAR / 365.0;
   double daily_city_miles = daily_miles * CITY_PERCENT/100.0;
   double daily_highway_miles = daily_miles*HIGHWAY_PERCENT/100.0;
   double daily_gas_consumed = daily_highway_miles / HIGHWAY_MPG +
   daily_city_miles / CITY_MPG;
   double gas_in_tank = USABLE_GAS;
   double price;
   double amount_purchased;
   double gallons_purchased;
   double total_gas_purchases = 0;

   for(int day = 0;day < 365*8; day++) { //If the day is less than the total number of days                 in 8 years, add one day
      cout << "Driving summary for day " << day << endl;
      cout << " highway miles: " << daily_highway_miles << endl;
      cout << " city miles   : " << daily_city_miles << endl;
      cout << " gas consumed : " << daily_gas_consumed << endl;
      gas_in_tank = gas_in_tank - daily_gas_consumed;
      cout << " gas in tank  : " << gas_in_tank << endl;

      if (gas_in_tank < 0.0) {
        cout << "  BUY GAS" << endl;
        gallons_purchased = USABLE_GAS - gas_in_tank;
        price = gasPrice(day);
        cout << "  price today is   : " << price << endl;
        cout << "  Gallons purchased: " << gallons_purchased << endl;
        cout << "  fillup cost      : " << gallons_purchased * price << endl;
        total_gas_purchases = total_gas_purchases + gallons_purchased * price;
        cout << "  total gas cost   : " << total_gas_purchases << endl;
        gas_in_tank = USABLE_GAS;
      }
   }

   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

double gasPrice(int day, int YEAR_NUM) {
if (int day=365) { //call YEAR_NUM, for day=365, increase YEAR_NUM by 1
    YEAR_NUM++;
    day = 0;
}
if (YEAR_NUM >= 4) {
    double currentPrice = FINAL_PRICE;
    currentPrice;

}
if (YEAR_NUM < 4) { //conditional price for the first four years
    double dailyIncrease = (FINAL_PRICE - INITIAL_PRICE) / (NUM_YEARS * 365);
    double currentPrice = (INITIAL_PRICE + day * dailyIncrease);
    return currentPrice;
}
}
```

Comment: There's not much point in having a `while` loop that runs once and then returns. Make it an `if`. Anyway, you don't return anything if `YEAR_NUM == 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return something in `gasPrice` that is outside of the `for` loop.  The compiler is saying there is a chance that neither of the `while` conditions will be met, in which case there is no value to  return.

On another note, the `while` loops do not make a lot of sense the way they are written.  Just make them `if` statements.

Comment: Can you please check my edited version of the code?  I replaced the 'for' loops with 'if' statements, and did my best to have the function make sense to me.  It still states that it may reach the end of a non-void function, though...

Comment: `double gasPrice(int day, int YEAR_NUM) 
{
if (int day=365) 
{ 
  //call YEAR_NUM, for day=365, increase YEAR_NUM by 1
    YEAR_NUM++;
    day = 0;
}
if (YEAR_NUM >= 4) 
{
    double currentPrice = FINAL_PRICE;
    currentPrice;

}
if (YEAR_NUM < 4) { //conditional price for the first four years
    double dailyIncrease = (FINAL_PRICE - INITIAL_PRICE) / (NUM_YEARS * 365);
    double currentPrice = (INITIAL_PRICE + day * dailyIncrease);
    return currentPrice;
}

return 1.00; //replace with sensible default value
}`


What I added was `return 1.00;`   replace that with a sensible default value

Comment: So, this works..  and instead of your 1.00, I said `return YEAR_NUM`

Now, the only thing it doesn't do is make the last four years use `FINAL_PRICE` as a static assignment.  I feel like I need to put in a statement that increments `YEAR_NUM` when `day = 365`, but I don't know where to put this in the code - I have tried multiple locations.

Comment: So this is what I came up with and it worked:

`double gasPrice(int day) {
        if (day > 365 * 4)  {
        double currentPrice = FINAL_PRICE;
        return currentPrice;
    }
        else {  //conditional price for the first four years
        double dailyIncrease = (FINAL_PRICE - INITIAL_PRICE) / (NUM_YEARS * 365);
        double currentPrice = (INITIAL_PRICE + day * dailyIncrease);
        return currentPrice;
    }
    return day;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think if you move "return currentPrice;" out of those two while loops, it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Function `gasPrice` has no return statement outside the for loop. As the function has a return type that is not void then if the return statement is absent the behaviour of the function will be undefined.